# Disable multiple dateField's

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a checkbox that controls 4 dateFields in ExtJs. I want to be able to give them a common property to be able to disable all fields with one command.
I assume there is a simpler way to do that. It works, but its a big block of code.

This is the checkBox's change event implementation so far:

```
 change: function (cmp, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {

        var dt1 = cmp.up().down('#Dtf1');
        dt1.setDisabled(newValue);
        var dt2 = cmp.up().down('#Dtf2');
        dt2.setDisabled(newValue);
        var dt3 = cmp.up().down('#Dtf3');
        dt3.setDisabled(newValue);
        var dt4 = cmp.up().down('#Dtf4');
        dt4.setDisabled(newValue);      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an attribute for example:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfieid',
    itemId: 'Dtf1',
    dtf: true
}
```

Then you'll be able to query like:

```
cmp.up().query('[dtf=true]').forEach(function(item){
    item.setDisabled(newValue);
});
```

Or can also use a query, like:

```
cmp.up().query('#Dtf1, #Dtf2, #Dtf3, #Dtf4').forEach(function(item){
    item.setDisabled(newValue);
});
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Much appreciated!